# Is it possible to see chrome console while being in source debugger?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I want to [debug javascript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) and see a [console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) at the same time (something like having two separate windows). I can not find a way to do this: either a debugger or a console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is an button that looks like <kbd>>=</kbd> in the top right of the developer tools

[image: Console]

When you click on that it opens a `drawer` that allows you to run console commands

---

**Update for 2017**

The icon has been removed and is now available through the dropdown menu (which also helpfully shows the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Esc</kbd>)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Press `escape` while in the debugger to open the console.

> You may also open up the console to experiment while paused. Hit the [Esc] key to bring the console into view.